The first time I installed Artifactory, the following mistake appeared after starting.http://localhost:8046 failed with error
2024-09-03T08:53:15.159Z [jfevt] [INFO ] [53a0db6498e5cd1c] [access_thin_client.go:101     ] [main                ] [                ] - Cluster join: Retry 35: Service registry ping failed, will retry. Error: Error while trying to connect to local router at address 'http://localhost:8046/access/api/v1/system/ping': Get "http://localhost:8046/access/api/v1/system/ping": dial tcp [::1]:8046: connect: connection refused [startup]
2024-09-03T08:53:18.098Z [jfmd ] [INFO ] [                ] [access_client_bootstrap.go:256] [main                ] - Cluster join: Retry 40: Service registry ping failed, will retry. Error: Error while trying to connect to local router at address 'http://localhost:8046/access': Get "http://localhost:8046/access/api/v1/system/ping": dial tcp [::1]:8046: connect: connection refused [access_client]

I've tried restarting the service and modifying the yaml file but nothing worked. I would like to ask where I can get technical support, or if I have solved a similar problem.
node:
        ## A unique id to identify this node.
        ## Default auto generated at startup.
        #   id: "art1"

        ## Default auto resolved by startup script
        ip: 192.168.31.35

Modified the yaml configuration file and reinstalled the service.

This error is not the root issue. It is just saying that some of the micro services (Metadata and Event, but probably all of them) could not reach the Access micro service.
You can look at the artifactory-service.log and look for the first error after startup, it will normally give the most useful information as to what went wrong.
You can of course also reach out to JFrog support for further help as well.
